# Compiling Python script to exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I recently created a script using Python 2.7 and pygame. I have tried using `py2exe`, but when I run the file it created, it gives me this error:

```
G:\Downloads2\GAME\dist\ANNECUTE.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import display: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
G:\Downloads2\GAME\dist\ANNECUTE.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import draw: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
G:\Downloads2\GAME\dist\ANNECUTE.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import image: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
G:\Downloads2\GAME\dist\ANNECUTE.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import pixelcopy: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
G:\Downloads2\GAME\dist\ANNECUTE.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import transform: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ANNECUTE.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "pygame\__init__.pyc", line 70, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: display module not available
(ImportError: No module named _view)
```

I used this in the `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "ANNECUTE.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
import pygame._view
```

To `zipextimporter.py`. This will import _view and should eliminate your problem.

Comment: Giving only a code snippet is bot enough, please extend your answer with a textual explanation, too (before it will be deleted)!

Comment: tHANK YOU ZACK. help me in my setup,py file where should i indicate if. here is my setup script from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "ANNECUTE.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)

Comment: should i include *import pygame._view* to the setup.py or to my sctript?

Comment: now that i added import pygame._view it gives me this error.     G:\Downloads2\GAME\dist\ANNECUTE.exe:51: RuntimeWarning: use font: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd
(ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ANNECUTE.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "pygame\__init__.pyc", line 70, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading pygame\font.pyd)